# Load GraphML or GEXF file from S3 into AWS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, networkx, graphml

I have a graph stored as GraphML format in s3. I would like to load it into Lambda, to use it later with a Python library called networkx. I was trying to read it as instructed in the [docs](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/generated/networkx.readwrite.graphml.read_graphml.html#networkx.readwrite.graphml.read_graphml) but it does not work because the path is not local but in s3 so it cannot find it.

I managed to get it working for JSON (code also below) but the file size with JSON gets very quickly huge so it is not an option.

```
import json
import boto3
import networkx as nx

client = boto3.client('s3')
s3_bucket_name = "<bucket_name>"
s3_object_key = "example.graphml"
#s3_object_key = "example.json"

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    content_object = client.get_object(Bucket=s3_bucket_name, Key=s3_object_key)
    file_content = content_object["Body"].read().decode('utf-8')
    nx.read_graphml(file_content)
    #json_content = json.loads(file_content)
    #print(json_content)
```

As sample graphml file you can try the following:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"])
G.add_edges_from([("A","C"), ("B","D"), ("B","E"), ("C", "E"), ("A", "E"), ("E", "D")])
nx.write_graphml_lxml(G, "example.graphml")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue you're running into is that the argument to the [read_graphml](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/generated/networkx.readwrite.graphml.read_graphml.html) function should be a file path not the GraphML string. If you want to use the string directly you can try using the [nx.parse_graphml](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/generated/networkx.readwrite.graphml.parse_graphml.html#networkx.readwrite.graphml.parse_graphml) function.